# How to get data From textboxt array with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im newbie here,

Usually I insert data to mysql with pure pHP, but now I must use jqyery ajax for some reason,.

I have **HTML** like this

```
<input name="produk[]"  value="kukis" class='produk' type="text" /><input name="qty[]" class="sipo" value='2'  type=text/><br>
<input name="produk[]"  value="puff" class='produk' type="text"/><input name="qty[]" class="sipo" value='3'  type=text/><br>

<input type='submit' value='save' name='save' id='woke'>
```

and **jquery** like this

```
<script>
  $(document).on("click","#woke",function() {

        var arr = [];
        var i = 0;
        $(".produk").each(function(index, element) {
               if ($(element).val()!=="") {             
                arr.push({
                    produk:$(element).val(),
                    qty:$(element).find('.sipo').val(),
                });
                i++;
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"tampil_data_all.php",
                    data:{"q": arr},
                    dataType:"html",
                    //data:{"q":tgl_satu,"qty":array_id,"accid":date_satu,"aksi":aksi},
                    success: function(data){

                        alert('Berhasil');
                        $('#tes').html(data);

                    }
                });



    });
</script>
```

the only I Hope is data send to **tampil_data_all.php** and I can use the data for insert

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";
$uki = $_POST['q'];
$min = "49086";             
                foreach ($uki as $item) {

                    $sql_kj="INSERT INTO order_kirim_wd SET  account_id  = '$min',
                                                         item_code  = '".$item['produk']."',
                                                         qty        = '".$item['qty']."',
                                                         periode1   = '2016-02-01',
                                                         periode2   = '2016-02-01',
                                                         tgl_upload = '2016-02-15 14:36:22'";
                                                         $hasil_input_kj = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_kj);
                    };


?>
```

But it still now send the data.

anyone can help fix this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: If `#woke` is a submit button and the issue is that page is reloading then you need to prevent the default form submit. Really not clear what you are asking though, or what the specific problem is

Comment: woke is only Id on submit button

Comment: Try changing first part to `$(document).on("click","#woke",function(event) { event.preventDefault(); /* your other code here*/`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$(element).find('.sipo').val()` doesn't find anything, because `.sipo` is not inside `.produk`.

What you want is `$(element).next('.sipo').val()` because the `.sipo` element is **after** the corresponding `.produk`.